# GSAP Horizontal Section Counting: How much sections have in horizontal section

Tags: gsap

i am trying to make GSAP horizontal scroll section, which i got from [this link](https://codepen.io/akapowl/pen/dyvygmj) but i need to add total counter like 02/10 same like [image: This is the example what i need]

i am just expecting that counter add under `pin-wrap` class with absolute and counter will change current page count when scroll